# Does enabling server side encryption on S3 impact reading data from s3 with other services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just started to enable server side encryption on all my buckets:

```
      MyBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketEncryption:
            ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
              - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
                SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```

I can still access the data through the console and my lambdas.

But for future use of the bucket and data on it. Does this encryption impact:

- Upload/download via presigned url?
- Manipulating the data in kinesis data firehose
- Analytics on the data via Athena?

Or can we use this services as is and AWS handles the encryption for us when the services try to access the data on the bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no impact if you are using `AES256` encryption. If you switched to using a KMS key for S3 encryption then you would have to provide IAM permissions to use the KMS key to any services interacting with the S3 bucket.